# Disable "-boot" distribution

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I configured a gradle project with multiple spring-boot subprojects, it seems to be building fine, but for some reason there are 2 archives in the "distributions" directory, one with the "-boot" suffix and the other without. The one with the suffix contains only current projects jar without any dependencies, the one without the suffix contains all that's needed to start the application. I'm pretty sure that last time I tried building spring-boot projects this other archive was not generated and I'm not sure what's changed. How can I stop the generation of these useless to me archives?

parent project build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    group '...'

    apply plugin: 'java'
}

subprojects {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.9
    targetCompatibility = 1.9

    repositories {
        ...
    }
}
```

spring-boot subproject build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

mainClassName = '...'

dependencies {
    ...
}

buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M5'
    }
    repositories {
        ...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The `boot` distribution packages your application's fat jar or war file. In other words all of its dependencies are packaged in the jar or war rather than in a separate `lib` directory.

If you don't want the archives from the `boot` distribution to be generated, you can disable the tasks that create them:

```
bootDistZip.enabled = false
bootDistTar.enabled = false
```

Comment: Ohh. I haven't checked the jar before, but I did now and you're correct, the dependencies are contained in it. The archive without the `boot` actually contains the dependencies twice, once in the projects jar file, and once in the `lib` directory. This can't be the intended behavior? Can you see anything wrong with my setup as posted above?

Comment: Could you show how this can be achieved using Kotlin?

Comment: @MichielHaisma https://stackoverflow.com/a/52838334/1384297 will hopefully show you what to do