# How do you disable distZip in a multi project builds on Kotlin DSL in Gradle

Tags: gradle, build, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have set up a Gradle multi project build using Kotlin DSL. This is `build.gradle.kts` in the root:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.2.70" apply false
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
      mavenCentral()
    }
}

subprojects {
    version = "1.0"
}
```

This is `sub/build.gradle.kts` in my sub project:

```
plugins {
    application
    kotlin("jvm")
}

application {
    mainClassName = "me.package.MainKt"
}

dependencies {
    compile(kotlin("stdlib"))
    compile("io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:1.6.10")
    compile("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3")
}
```

When I run `$ gradle build` the `application` plugin creates me a distribution in `sub/build/distribution`.

I don't need the zip distribution and I want no version number in the tar distribution. Both should be trivial in the regular `build.gradle` like:

```
distZip.enabled = false
distTar.archiveName = "${project.name}.tar"
```

Whatever I try using Kotlin DSL, I get `Unresolved reference: distZip`. How do I address the `distZip` and `distTar` tasks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need is:

```
val distZip by tasks
distZip.enabled = false
val distTar by tasks
distTar.archiveName = "${project.name}.tar"
```

or:

```
tasks.getByName<Zip>("distZip").enabled = false
tasks.getByName<Tar>("distTar").archiveName = "${project.name}.tar"
```